# how to select a subset from a std::vector or list?

Tags: c++, boost, stl

c++ gurus:

there are quite some useful c++ stl algorithms such as find or search. However, it seems that they only return one single interator.

what if i want to do a SQL style 'select' for a STL container? say, a vector (might be extended to list or map). something like

```
std::pair<vector::iterator, vector::iterator> select(std::vector::iterator begin, std::vector::iterator end, Comparor equal_to)
```

the output should be a range, something like a std::pair, which is similiar to the return value of the methods in boost::multi-index

is there anything like this in stl? or any solid libararies similiar?

Comment: What if the subset is not a contiguous subrange?

Comment: There is nothing like this in the standard library.

One option would be boost::Range, and specifically [boost::range::filtered](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/filtered.html)

Comment: @KerrekSB the output elements are supposed to be, most often, not continugous

Comment: @ccfenix: if the output elements are not contiguous, then how on earth do you expect a pair of `vector::iterator` objects to tell you which ones they are out of the whole vector? The only way to achieve that would be to copy or move the equal elements into a contiguous part of a vector, which you've said elsewhere is too expensive.

Comment: @Steve I shoudl have explain my problem more specifically: i want the output to be a container of iterators, rather than a container of deeply copied objects (which is gonna be huge)

Comment: OK, now you're talking sense :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have basically two approaches:

1) The thing you say in a comment above, write (iterators pointing at) the results into a container of iterators. That's going to look something like this:

```
template <typename ForwardIterator, typename OutputIterator, typename UnaryPredicate>
void select_iterators(ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last, 
                      OutputIterator out, UnaryPredicate pred) {
    while (first != last) {
        if pred(*first) *out++ = first;
        ++first;
    }
}
```

Then you call it like:

```
vector<Foo> myfoos;
vector<vector<Foo>::iterator> results;
select_iterators(myfoos.begin(), myfoos.end(), std::back_inserter(results), some_comparator);
```

You could actually define `select_iterators` in terms of other algorithms, using `copy_if` and `boost::counting_iterator`, but I don't think it's worth it when the direct implementation is so simple. It would look like:

```
template <typename ForwardIterator, typename OutputIterator, typename UnaryPredicate>
void select_iterators(ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last, 
                      OutputIterator out, UnaryPredicate pred) {
    std::copy_if(
        boost::make_counting_iterator(first), 
        boost::make_counting_iterator(last),
        out,
        [&](ForwardIterator it) { return pred(*it); }
    );
}
```

2) Instead of testing all the values up front and writing the results somewhere, define an iterator that advances over the original range each time it is incremented until it finds the next match. Boost provides two ways of doing this, `boost::filter_iterator` and `boost::adaptors::filter`. So you could write:

```
auto results = boost::adaptors::filter(myfoos, some_comparator);
```

Then whatever you want to do with your results, you can iterate from `results.begin()` to `results.end()` as if it were a container. It's not a container, it doesn't satisfy the whole container interface. It satisfies an interface defined by Boost, named Range, which amounts to "can be iterated over". It's actually just a filtered view of `myfoos`, so no `Foo` object is copied or even moved.

Comment: This might be a bit late but why isn't it enough to simply use `std::copy_if(src.begin(), src.end(), dst.begin(), pred)` ?

Comment: @ZivS: because of the comment made by the original questioner, " i want the output to be a container of iterators, rather than a container of deeply copied objects"

Comment: @ZivS: it did take me a careful read to figure out out, though, despite the fact I wrote it :-) Other than the return value, the difference between my first implementation of `select_iterators` and `copy_if` is just that mine has `= first` where `copy_if` would have `= *first`.

Answer (score 4):

If you can modify your vector [std::partition](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition) would be the choice. Here how you would call it:

```
std::vector<int>::iterator p =
    std::partition(v.begin(), v.end(), you_predicate);
```

You're answer lie between `v.begin()` and `p`.

Comment: thanks! this shoudl involve a lot of copy or swap, right? i am afraid it's too expensive to me

Comment: Complexity is explained in the linked page. If your copy algorithm is costly, kt is not  a  good choice.

Answer (score 2):

You might be looking for [`boost::range`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/range/doc/html/index.html)

A `boost::range` is effectively a pair of iterators delimiting a range of elements of a container. The library includes various algorithms which return a range from a range (such as the range of equivalent values in container, with a user-supplied equivalence functor).

Answer (score 1):

```
template<typename ForwardIterator, typename OutputIterator, typename UnaryPredicate>
    void find_elements(ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last, OutputIterator out, UnaryPredicate pred)
    {
        while(first != last)
        {
            if(pred(*first))
                *out++ = first;
            ++first;
        }
    }
```

Things to keep in mind:

1.) You said that you want your container to be of `iterator` rather than `const_iterator`. The type will be the same as the begin and end range you pass to the function. For example, the type will be `const_iterator` for `const` containers, it will also be `const_iterator` if you use `vector::cbegin` and `vector::cend`, and it won't compile if you use differing iterators such as `vector::begin` and `vector::cend`.

2.) Vectors often lose their iterator validity, so be careful with using these iterators. If you add to the vector, for example, every iterator returned by this function could be invalid. To prevent this, either use a different container (e.g. list) or use `vector::reserve`.

3.) The forward iterator has to be something that supports ++, and when dereferenced, has the same type as InputIterator (e.g. `vector<int>::iterator`). It must also remain a valid iterator after incrementing it, or the function would be meaningless. The output iterator must go to a place with enough space to hold all the iterators found to satsify `pred`. If you do not know the space in advance, you can use `std::back_inserter` from `<iterator>` with a container that has `container::push_back` defined, and it will grow as needed.

Here is a test of the function for you to understand how it works.

```
int main()
{
    vector<string> ss = {"hi", "yog", "engils", "pog"};

    // Define a predicate
    auto isSizeThree = [](string const &s)
    {
        return s.size() == 3;
    };

    // example one: Somehow I know how many satisfy the predicate. I just don't know where they are.
    vector<vector<string>::iterator> answer(2);
    find_elements(begin(ss), end(ss), begin(answer), isSizeThree);

    // Check answer
    cout << "Test 1" << endl;
    for(auto entry : answer)
        cout << *entry << endl;

    // Example two: I don't know how many there will be (more typical). If I use a continer with stuff in it - it will stack right on the back of it!
    find_elements(begin(ss), end(ss), back_inserter(answer), isSizeThree);

    // Check answer (has the answer from test 1 still in it)
    cout << "Test 2" << endl;
    for(auto entry : answer)
        cout << *entry << endl;

    // Example Three: Same as test 2 but clear the ansewr vector first.
    answer.clear();
    find_elements(begin(ss), end(ss), back_inserter(answer), isSizeThree);

    // Check answer
    cout << "Test 3" << endl;
    for(auto entry : answer)
        cout << *entry << endl;
}
```